# loop through all possible if statements

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a way to loop through all possible if statements.  I am looping through a list of items and i want to see what combinations of if statements the items are true.

So when I look at the first item in the list, I want to see if item passes the first if condition and not the second if condition, the second if condition and not the first if condition, both the first and second if conditions, and neither the if conditions.

This is kind of what I am looking for but I am having trouble pairing the for loop with the if statements.

```
foreach(var i in items)
{
    for(int if1 = 0; if1 < 1; if1++)
    {
        for(int if2 = 0; if2 < 1; if2++)
        {
            if if1 = 0 and if2 = 0 then check if both if statements are false
            if if1 = 1 and if2 = 0 then check if first if is true and second is false
            if if1 = 0 and if2 = 1 then check if first if is false and second is true
            if if1 = 1 and if2 = 1 then check if first if is true and second if is true
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple version of what I am trying to do.  Eventually it will check a few dozen if statement possibilities.

Comment: The way you're stating your problem is extremely convoluted and I am having an hard time understanding what you're asking / trying to accomplish.

Comment: where are your if statements held, each one is a method?

Comment: Question titles should start with a capital letter and end with a question mark if possible.  Think about how your question looks in the question list with all other questions.  Starting a question with a lowercase letter is just lazy.

Comment: A few *dozen* conditions? Thats a pretty big code smell if you ask me.

Comment: Would it make more sense to simply loop through the correct number of choices (2 ^ 12 = 4096), and use binary operators to use the bits in the count to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. But if I understand correctly, something like this should work:

```
foreach(var i in items)
{
    // Fake conditions for the purpose of example
    bool firstCondition = i.Value1 == 17,
        secondCondition = i.Value2 == 37;

    for(int if1 = 0; if1 < 1; if1++)
    {
        for(int if2 = 0; if2 < 1; if2++)
        {
            bool localCondition1 = if1 == 0 ? !firstCondition : firstCondition,
                localCondition2 = if2 == 0 ? !secondCondition : secondCondition;

            if (localCondition1 && localCondition2)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above assumes that you have just a single thing to do, based on the conditional evaluation of the original conditions. If you have different things to do depending on the conditions, you might want something like this:

```
foreach(var i in items)
{
    // Fake conditions for the purpose of example
    bool firstCondition = i.Value1 == 17,
        secondCondition = i.Value2 == 37;

    for(int if1 = 0; if1 < 1; if1++)
    {
        for(int if2 = 0; if2 < 1; if2++)
        {
            bool localCondition1 = if1 == 0 ? !firstCondition : firstCondition,
                localCondition2 = if2 == 0 ? !secondCondition : secondCondition;

            if (localCondition1 && localCondition2)
            {
                switch (if1 + if2 * 2)
                {
                case 0:
                    // if1 == 0, if2 == 0
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // if1 == 1, if2 == 0
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // if1 == 0, if2 == 0
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // if1 == 1, if2 == 1
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you would replace the initialization of `firstCondition` and `secondCondition` with the actual conditions you are testing.

Though IMHO, if you are really just trying to test the possible combinations, you should get rid of the inner loops altogether and just write the `if` statements out explicitly:

```
foreach(var i in items)
{
    // Fake conditions for the purpose of example
    bool firstCondition = i.Value1 == 17,
        secondCondition = i.Value2 == 37;

    if (!firstCondition)
        if (!secondCondition)
            // if0 == 0, if1 == 0
        else
            // if0 == 0, if1 == 1
    else
        if (!secondCondition)
            // if0 == 1, if1 == 0
        else
            // if0 == 1, if1 == 1
}
```

If none of those address your issue, you should think a lot harder about how to express your question, and then edit the question so that it's more comprehensible.